# Strange Strings in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, string

I have two strings,one string which is an output from an API and
another which is stored in the MYSQL Database as longtext.I am trying
to compare these two strings,so here's what I did:

```
 echo $stringfromMyDatabase;
 echo "<br">;
 echo $stringfromMyApi;
 echo "<br>";
 echo strcmp($stringfromMyDatabase,$stringfromMyapi);
 echo "<br>";
 echo "StringfrommyDatabase :".strlen($stringfromMyDatabase)."and StringfromApi:".strlen($stringfromMyApi);
```

and Here's the output I obtained:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1
StringfrommyDatabase :25 and StringfromApi:17
```

Although the string looks exactly similar while echoing them out,How
do I know how and where these two strings differ and How do i print
the two strings with all special characters enlcosed?

Any help with proper explanation will be highly appreciated!

Comment: silly typo error that;s strcmp() @Pang

Answer (score 0):

use var_dump($stringfromMyDatabase, $stringfromMyApi) and look at this.

Comment: :Shows string(25) "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"

Answer (score 0):

The strings are different according to the strlen you performed on them. I am pretty sure that your database stored the string with additional space characters (blank spaces, tabs, ...).

Try this:

```
$len = strlen($stringfromMyDatabase);
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
if ($stringfromMyDatabase[$i] != $stringfromMyapi[$i])
  echo "--{$stringfromMyDatabase[$i]}-- (code " . ord($stringfromMyDatabase[$i]) .
    ") != --{$stringfromMyapi[$i]}-- (code " . ord($stringfromMyapi[$i]) . ") @ char pos {$i}\n";
}
```

This will show you where the strings differ and what are the (possibly non printable) characters that are different.

Comment: why should it be ?i am storing the same string retrieved from the api in to the database..using the insert query command but while retrieving the string the length differs why is this happening?

Comment: I think without using these long lines of code we can use str_replace("\","\\",$string) but in this case "\\" reports an error why so?

Comment: You have to escape your backslashes. About the piece of code I gave you, its only purpose is to show you where the differences are between your two strings. Try it to see what differs.

Comment: I am storing a particular string inside a MYSQL database as longtext but when I am retrieving the same string,the length of the original string which is exactly the same as the one stored in the database differs by its length? Is Mysql storing the text with additional characters? @NaeiKinDus

Comment: That's possible. Use this code to see what is appended to the original string.